# URL Routing for nested states in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

So I am using UI-Router to build my AngularJS app. However I am confused as to how the URL Routing works in case of nested states mainly due to the conflicting ideas (as per my understanding) provided in the wiki for UI-Router.

**The first idea**

[image: idea 1]
Hence maybe abstract state is used below

[image: idea 1]

**The second idea**

[image: idea 2]

As given in the documentation (first idea), url of parent state is prepended to that of it's children only in case of 'abstract':true property defined on the parent state.

However the documentation (second idea) also mentions how the above is a default feature.

Aren't the two ideas above conflicting for the same concept ? Or have I completely misunderstood them ?

Comment: Please be more specific. We have no idea what conflict you have perceived or what specific problems you may be encountering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the documentation statements are correct. Maybe not clear for someone - but correct. It simply says:

1) No inheritance of `url: "..url..."` **setting**. It means, that child state **won't** have the `url` set with **the same value as parent**. Both values are independent.

2) There is implicit `url` concatenation. Child state `url` *(in address bar, not the setting)* is built from all its ancestors `url`.

So, the **documentation is correct**. This [example is just for](http://plnkr.co/edit/BgevH5Rc7PJ9pTWJdXTk?p=preview) play ... It shows what we know. Child has different `url` **setting** then parent. Child state `url` in address bar is build from its `url` **setting** - prefixed with parent(s) url

```
// NON abstract
  .state('parent1', {
      abstract: false,
      url: "/parent1",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
  .state('parent1.child1', { 
      url: "/child1",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
// abstract
  .state('parent2', {
      abstract: true,
      url: "/parent2",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
  .state('parent2.child2', { 
      url: "/child2",
      templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
  })
```

url in href:

```
non abstract
<a href="#/parent1">
<a href="#/parent1/child1">
abstract
<a href="#/parent2"> - cannot navigate there - is abstract
<a href="#/parent2/child2">
```

Comment: Aahh....so to summarize - URL concatenation takes place irrespective whether parent state is abstract or not. Right ?

Comment: As you expected - exactly. I understand that it could be confusing without experience with UI-Router... but after while.. this is pretty usual scenario... hope it helps a bit ;)

Answer (score 1):

They are trying to show concept only in this doc,so don't expect actual example here.

This is common concept for ui router.

Behavior of abstract state.

1) You can not call **abstract** state directly, So here we can not call contacts state directly

> **/contsacts**  This redirect to our default state

2) Abstract state should have always at least one child state. So we can call here

> **/contact/list** as contacts.list state

3) Parent state's template must have

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

directive where child state will propagate.

Comment: Actually that's not my problem/concern. The question is for prepending URLs, is abstract:true required or not?

Comment: @Navin `abstract:true` isn't required for prepending URLs. `abstract:true` is being used to abstract the parent state and let child state overrides it.

Comment: @Navin This is not necessary to use abstract:true for prepend  url. Abstract:true only require when there is no need to show html template itself, but this template helps child state's template to render